# How to write tests for a UIViewRepresentable in a Swift Package

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create a swift package for my project that has some shared UI elements in it and I want to write some tests for it

This is one of the view

```
//
//  TextField.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by Development on 05/03/2021.
//

#if !os(macOS)
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public struct TextFieldRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Environment(\.isSecureField) var isSecureField: Bool
    @Environment(\.isFirstResponder) var isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>?
    @Environment(\.placeholder) var placeholder: String?
    @Environment(\.keyboardType) var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
    @Environment(\.returnKeyType) var returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType
    @Environment(\.textContentType) var contentType: UITextContentType?
    @Environment(\.autoCapitalisation) var autoCapitalisation: Bool
    @Environment(\.autoCorrection) var autoCorrection: Bool
    @Environment(\.font) var font: Font?

    let onCommit: (() -> Bool)?
    
    public init( text: Binding<String>,  onCommit: (() -> Bool)? = nil ) {
        _text = text
        self.onCommit = onCommit
    }
    
    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        syncValues(context: context, textField: textField)
        return textField
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        syncValues(context: context, textField: uiView)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let isFirstResponderValue = isFirstResponder?.wrappedValue {
                switch isFirstResponderValue {
                case true:
                    uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
                case false:
                    uiView.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func syncValues(context _: Context, textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = text
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureField
        textField.textContentType = contentType
        textField.keyboardType = keyboardType
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        textField.font = UIFont.preferredFont(from: font)
        textField.autocapitalizationType = autoCapitalisation ? .sentences : .none
        textField.returnKeyType = returnKeyType
        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textField.autocorrectionType = autoCorrection ? .yes : .no
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        private let parent: TextFieldRepresentable

        init(parent: TextFieldRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        public func textFieldShouldReturn(_: UITextField) -> Bool {
            return parent.onCommit?() ?? true
        }

        public func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.$text.wrappedValue = textField.text ?? ""
        }

        public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_: UITextField) {
            parent.isFirstResponder?.wrappedValue = true
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

I want to test that when I am applying a modifier the underlying UIView responds to the changes. Is there a way to load this view in an SPM unit test and get the underlying UITextField so I can see the the modifier worked ?

I tried using [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect/issues?q=UIViewRepresentable) and [ViewInpsector](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector) but without luck.

Also I noticed that in the SPM even if I construct the View the **makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField** and **updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context)** functions are never getting called. I tried the same thing in an iOS project unit test and functions got called correctly. Check the code bellow

```
import Foundation
import XCTest
import SwiftUI

@testable import UI

final class TextFieldRepresentableTests: XCTestCase {
    

    
    var view:TextFieldRepresentable!
    var controller:UIHostingController<TextFieldRepresentable>!
    override func setUp() {
        view = TextFieldRepresentable(text: .constant("Test"))
        controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = controller
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    func test_isSecureField_IsTrue_ShouldTextFieldBeSecure() {
        view.makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldRepresentable>())
        
    }
}
```

Comment: could you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Testing the subviews created by your `UIViewRepresentable` requires instantiating a `UIWindow` that runs in the context of a simulator instance (or a device).

For the above to happen, you need to have an iOS app that is used as a host for the unit tests. Unfortunately, at this point, SPM doesn't provide an option to create iOS apps (not sure how feasible this would be to add).

A workaround would be to:

1. create a dummy iOS app
2. create a test target for that iOS app
3. link the package to the test target, this assumes that you build a library target instead of a test target in the package

You can add the package as a local package, and include the project in your source control (e.g. git). This way people who checkout the package can also run the tests.

However, you might want to reconsider your design testing strategy here. For example, you could extract all that `UITextField` logic into an adapter class that doesn't have any SwiftUI dependencies, and test that class instead. This will result in better and faster tests.